# VBA t-Test: Two-Sample Assuming Unequal Variances

Tags: vba, excel

How do you code in VBA a t-test: two-sample assuming unequal variances? Here's what I have so far. When I run it, a window says "Sorry, we couldn't find C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\ATPVBAEN.XLAM. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

```
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Pttestv", ActiveSheet.Range("A2:" & "A" & 
(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value + 1)), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("B2:" & "B" & (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value + 
1)), "", False, 0.05, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `Application.Run`, add a reference to `atvbaen.vbs` to your project (using `Tools/References` in the VBA editor) after doing this, you should be able to just do something like:

```
Pttestv ActiveSheet.Range("A2:" & "A" & (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value +1)),  ActiveSheet.Range("B2:" & "B" & (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value + 1)), "", False, 0.05, 0
```

If you really want to use `Application.Run`, you would need to include the full path to the file `ATPVBAEN.XLAM`. VBA is looking for it in your documents folder, which is not where it is located.

Comment: I can't find atvbean.vbs or atpvbean.xlam in the Tools/References tab.

Comment: @JakeKruk If the add-in is installed it should appear towards the top of the references list.

Comment: Had to enable the Analysis Toolpack for VBA. Thanks!